# Links in Webview followed by dots

Tags: java, android, web

After links which are too long, I am getting ...

for e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/List_...

how do i get the full link?

here is my code

```
wv_result_display.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    wv_result_display.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv_result_display.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   wv_result_display.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


wv_result_display.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/searchq="+tv_query.getText().toString());
```

Here is my output
[image]

Here is my layout file

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv_result_of_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
```

Comment: Please send the layout file

Comment: I guess it's not possible from our side. It depends on the website loaded. If it is mobile responsive / optimized then it will only load the mobile version of the website.